# Even number of 2s in prime factorization of number

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am doing a Haskell practice problem that involves writing a function that returns true if 2 divides an even number of times into a parameter num. If num is odd for example, this returns True since 2 divides in 0 times, and 0 is even. 8 as a parameter returns False, since 2 divides in 3 times, and 3 is odd.
I know how to do this problem using two parameters, in which the second parameter is a counter, and you keep dividing your first parameter by 2 until it equals 1, and if the counter mod 2 == 0, then return True. But we are supposed to do it with only a number as a parameter,... so how can I do that?
My function,

```
isGreen :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isGreen num count
    | (num==1)&&(count `mod` 2 == 0) = True
    | (num==1)&&(count `mod` 2 /= 0) = False
    | otherwise = isGreen (div num 2) (count + 1)
```

Comment: You can even determine this directly by using `countTrailingZeros`, is that within the scope of this question?

Comment: @chepner 8=2^3, and 8 is divisible by 4, but it is not a green number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using an exclusive or function. I don't believe this is incorporated into Haskell, so you could make one yourself

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor True True = False
xor True False = True
xor False True = True
xor False False = False

isGreen :: Int -> Bool
isGreen num
    | (num < 0) = isGreen (-num)
    | (mod num 2 /= 0) = True
    | num > 1 = xor True (isGreen (div num 2))
    | num == 1 = True
```

The reason this works is cause we keep flipping between True and False every single time we climb back up the call stack.

```
Example: isGreen 8 =
xor True (isGreen 4) = 
xor True (xor True (isGreen 2) =
xor True (xor True (xor True isGreen 1)) = 
xor True (xor True (xor True True)) = 
xor True (xor True False) = xor True (True) = 
False
```

Comment: `xor` is just `/=`

Comment: You only use `xor` for `xor True` which is just `not`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your version doesn't give the right answer for odd numbers:

```
> isGreen 0 3
False
>
```

because it checks for termination using `n == 1` when it should use `odd n` instead.

Anyway, as an alternative, you can construct a direct recursive definition by observing that if `x` is divisible by 4, then `isGreen x` is the same as `` isGreen (x `quot` 4) ``.  Otherwise, divisibility by 2 will give the answer:

```
isGreen x | x == 0         = error "zero is neither green nor not green"
          | x `rem` 4 == 0 = isGreen (x `quot` 4)
          | even x         = False  -- one two left over
          | otherwise      = True   -- no twos left over
```

giving:

```
> map isGreen [1..10]
[True,False,True,True,True,False,True,False,True,False]
>
```

As a side note,  I've used `quot` and `rem` here out of habit.  At least on Intel architectures and using primitive integer types, they are faster than `div` and `mod` when you don't care about the sign of the result, so I've kind of gotten used to using them when testing for divisibility.  Along the same lines, some people might write the second case as:

```
| let (q,r) = x `quotRem` 4, r == 0 = isGreen q
```

on the grounds that the single `quotRem` call will save a division over separate `rem` and `quot` calls.  Admittedly, both of these optimizations are rather silly here.